# How to make Monit “check process” conditional inside docker based on docker run args?

Tags: docker, monit, environment-variables

I would like to make Monit's "check process" work conditionally based on an env variable.

Here's the pseudo-code of what I would like to achieve(not a valid monit config syntax):

```
[ -n "$run_foo" ] && check process foo ....
```

My use case:
I have a docker image that starts monit process like this:

```
CMD ["/bin/monit", "-c","/config/monit.conf"]
```

Monit then starts various daemons.

Now, I would like to be able to tell at run time which daemons I want to start in a particular container created from this image, like this:

```
docker run --env="run_foo=1;run_bar=1" ...
```

I am aware of monit unmonitor, and similar args, however I believe they don't serve my purpose.

Thought about something like this:

```
start program="/bin/bash -c '[ -n \"$run_foo\" ] && /bin/foo .."
```

However, seems like it will cause monit to spin continuously trying to start and monitor things that shouldn't be started.

I am aware of possibility of using different monit config files, or using different docker images - these don't qualify as an answer.

Other ideas appreciated.

Comment: Are you using any configuration management tool? Puppet? Ansible?

Comment: no. you suggesting using them inside docker image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly that is not how Monit is working.

Monit is there **to react** to states you define. If you use it as init system (what is totally fine and working) you have to have a config file that is built for your needs.

You could, however, try to hack it with a little `sed` or something.

The idea is to have a `monitrc` with all configs, but all inactive and activate them on first start. Like:

```
#check process foo with pidfile /run/foo.pid # proc-foo
#  onreboot nostart # proc-foo
#  mode passive # proc-foo

#check process bar with pidfile /run/bar.pid # proc-bar
#  onreboot nostart # proc-bar
#  mode passive # proc-bar

check program firststart path "/bin/bash -c /tmp/firststart.sh" # first-start
```

While `/tmp/firststart.sh` is something like:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Uncomment Lines Per Config:
[[ -n "${run_foo}" ]] && sed -i 's/^#\(.*\) # proc-foo$/\1/' /etc/monitrc
[[ -n "${run_bar}" ]] && sed -i 's/^#\(.*\) # proc-bar$/\1/' /etc/monitrc

# Delete FirstStart Line
sed -i '/^.*# first-start$/d' /etc/monitrc

# Force reload of monit config
kill -SIGHUP $(cat /run/monit.pid)
```

Comment: thx, looks like not a bad workaround